# What's the purpose of location.href + ''

Tags: javascript

I found `url = location.href + ''` in [URI.js](https://github.com/medialize/URI.js/blob/master/src/URI.js#L44) , according to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535866), the `href` property is `string`, so why concat an empty string here?

Is there any browser compatibility issues here?

Comment: programmers make mistakes too

Comment: File it wherever you also filed `typeof(x)` and `void(0)`.

Answer (score 1):

It should be a string.

But take the advice of Walter Donovan from *The Last Crusade*:

> "Be very careful. Don't trust anybody."

[image]

Comment: The advice is nice, but if the interface says it will always return string, so we will just take it as string. We will only add some hack until some issues show up

Comment: We're talking abour web browsers. Notoriously terrible at meeting specifications and difficult to test thoroughly. Are you really so confident that there are no circumstances in which IE6 or BlackBerry or PhantomJS could possibly place a null value here? It's the same principle as implementing network protocols: Be conservative in what you send and liberal in what you receive.

Answer (score -3):

I think there are not any browser compatibility issues...

```
url = location.href + ''
```

the code mean add string type

Java is a complect language that see`int` and `double` not same . so you need to convert that.

example

```
var prize = 10 // int
var txtPrize = price + '' // change price to string
```

if we use `price.length` that will return `undefinied`

if we use `txtPrize.length` that will return `2`

another example

```
var txtPrize = "10" // string
var prize = txtPrize * 1 // change to int
```

if we try using  `Total = txtPrize + 40` that will return `1040`

if we try using  `Total = prize + 40` that will return `50`

CMIIW

Comment: It's a string already, so that type conversion is not needed.  However, in `location+''` does make sense to convert to string as `window.location` is a `Location` object, not a string.  The Location object just has a convenient `toString()` method that gets invoked that returns the whole href (more or less, I haven't read the docs to see if there's anything special about it).